# Создание новой базы данных в LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

В *msdn* есть статья "[Как динамически создать базу данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb399420%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)"

Я попытался создать новую базу данных. Но база данных не создается.

В чем причина?

Вот описание ошибки:

> Error!
>   При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или
>    с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя
>    экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения
>   . (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Ошибка при обнаружении указанно
>   го сервера или экземпляра)

**Main.cs**

```
using System;

//добавить ссылку
using System.Linq;

//добавить ссылку
//подключить пространство имен
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Linq;

//добавить ссылку
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

/*создание базы данных*/
public class MyDataBase : DataContext {
 public Table<MyTable> Books;
 public MyDataBase(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}

/*создание таблицы*/
[Table(Name = "Book")]
public class MyTable {
 [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
 public int IDBook;
 [Column]
 public string Name;
 [Column]
 public int Amount;
 [Column]
 public decimal Price;
}

class Program {
 public static int Main() {
  try {
   MyDataBase db = new MyDataBase(@"d:\abc.mdf");
   db.CreateDatabase();
   Console.WriteLine("База успешно создана!");
  }
  catch(Exception exc) {
   Console.WriteLine("Error!\n\n{0}", exc.Message);
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
  return 0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался! Все дело в строке соединения! В *msdn* это почему-то было не указано. Вот тебе и *msdn*, доверяй, но проверяй! Строка соединения должна выглядеть вот так в моем примере.

```
MyDataBase db = new MyDataBase(@"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=d:\abc.mdf;");
```

Comment: Вообще-то, это указано. Но в разделе про LocalDB, а не про Entity Framework.